# Can't access Claim by it's key after login with ASP.NET Core Identity in .NET 6 Project

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a Blazor project in .NET 6. I am using ASP.NET Core Identity for login. After login, I have set some **Claims** with a **custom Key**. Here is the code:

**Login Code:**

```
var createdUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.UserName.Trim());

var LoginResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.UserName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
if (LoginResult.Succeeded)
{
    var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(createdUser);
    
    var claims = new List<Claim>()
    {
        new Claim("UserId", createdUser?.Id),
        new Claim("Username", createdUser?.UserName),
        new Claim("OrganizationId", createdUser?.OrganizationId)
    };

    if(userRoles!= null && userRoles.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var role in userRoles)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }
    }   

    var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
    var claimPrincpal = new ClaimsPrincipal(appIdentity);
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimPrincpal;
    User.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
    
    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

After Login I have a **UserInfoService** class and there I have some code to get the Claim value. Here is the code below:

```
public class UserInfoService : IUserInfoService
{
    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authProvider;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    
    public UserInfoService(
        AuthenticationStateProvider authProvider,
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _authProvider = authProvider;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
           

    public async Task<string> GetUserName()
    {
        var auth = await _authProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = auth.User;

        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            var claimsIdentity = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            var userName = claimsIdentity.FindFirst("Username")?.Value;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName))
                return null;

            return userName;
        }
    }        
}
```

And In my **Program.cs** file I have the below settings for identity:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
           .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
           .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
           .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

But whenever I call **GetUserName** method to get the username from Claim, it returns null. I tried to debug the code and during debugging whenever the breakpoint comes upon this line (**var claimsIdentity = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;**), I hover the mouse and have the below information into the Claims Property, which I don't understand how to access. I don't even see the Claims Key (UserId, Username) which I set during the login.
[image]

Can anyone help to find the answer to how can I access Claims Key and Value?

Comment: Are you using the `UseAuthentication()` and `UseAuthorization()` middlewares?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
> var claimPrincpal = new ClaimsPrincipal(appIdentity);
> Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimPrincpal;
> User.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
> ```

By using the above code, the new claim will be added to the HttpContext.User, it will store data while processing a single request. The collection's contents are discarded after a request is processed.

So, I suggest you can store the Claims in the `AspNetUserClaims` table, you could use the `UserManager.AddClaimAsync()` method to add the specified claim to the user, and then use the `SignInManager` or ApplicationDbContext to get tye user's claims. Check the following sample code (Login post method):

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    //find current user.
    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
    //based on user information to query the user and role policy table. Here I set the user role directly.
    var userrole = "User";
    if (user.UserName.Contains("aa"))
    {
        userrole = "Admin";
    }

    //get the current user claims principal
    var claimsPrincipal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
    //get the current user's claims.
    var claimresult = claimsPrincipal.Claims.ToList();
    //it it doesn't contains the Role claims, add a role claims
    if (!claimresult.Any(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role))
    { 
        //add claims to current user. 
        await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userrole));
    }
    //refresh the Login
    await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
     
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from the [Lik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73315793/2975931) Now I have added the below code in my login page and it's working fine.

```
var claims = new List<Claim>()
{
    new Claim("UserId", createdUser?.Id),
    new Claim("UserName", createdUser?.UserName),
    new Claim("OrganizationId", createdUser?.OrganizationId),
    new Claim("OrganizationName", OrganizationName)
};

var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(createdUser);

if (userRoles != null && userRoles.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var role in userRoles)
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
    }                            
}

var claimsPrincipal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(createdUser);
var claimResult = claimsPrincipal.Claims.ToList();

if (claims != null && claims.Count > 0)
{
    await _userManager.AddClaimsAsync(createdUser, claims.ToList());                            
}

await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(createdUser);
```